# is it possible to change the Wrapper "<div>" of Image in Image2 ckeditor plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using image2 plugin with CKeditor, I come to case where I cant use "Div" as image wrapper.

Image2 plugin use "Div" a wrapper on "Figure" tag when Captioned widget is used with center alginment

Like : Captioned widget with center alginment

```
│ center │<wrapper class=”center”>      │<div class=”center”>             │
│        │ <figure />                   │ <figure />                      │
│        │</wrapper>                    │</div>                           |
```

So is it possible to replace this wrapper "Div" with any other tag?

Answer (score 0):

The html code is must me close figure..

```
 <wrapper class="center">
        <figure></figure> 
 </wrapper>
```

And the jQuery code is replace all wrapper tag which have contain's center class.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("wrapper.center").each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith( "<div class="+ $( this ).attr('class') +">" + $(this).html() + "</div>" );
    });
 </script>
```

If you want remove specific only one tag then the jQuery is.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("wrapper.center").replaceWith( "<div class="+ $( this ).attr('class') +">" + $(this).html() + "</div>" );
 </script>
```